# Not able to see Videos in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, video, troubleshooting, media-player, codec

I can run all different formats of videos in all different players but i dont get to see video in any, i can just hear the audio. Is it because of some codec or some missing driver?

Also, i can see the videos online by running on any browser.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: we could use more details, such as what operating system, what brand/model of machine, etc...

Answer (score 1):

First, [update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&displaylang=en) your DirectX.
Second, update your VGA driver. (Can give you a link if you tell us what VGA have you got.)
Third, install a codec pack with player. My favourite is [CCCP](http://cccp-project.net/) pack.
(On the website there is a CCCP Insurgent. It detects the conflicts. Try running it first before installing the codec pack. Something may have gone wrong between the codecs.)

(In browsers, you use Flash Player. It comes with codec support AND the video on the other side is converted in a format which Flash Player can play without a problem.)

Answer (score 0):

The codec pack I like best is [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm), whose installation does more verifications on your PC than most other codec-packs.

Install it and see if it solves the problem.
If it doesn't, then some more analysis of your problem is required.

Comment: I just installed this codec. No improvement.

Comment: @Amby: Media Player Classic comes with K-Lite. Does it also not show video?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be on the video card driver, open up the Device manager (Start -> Run -> devmgmt.msc) and see if any drivers are missing. I've never liked those codec packs and always had some problems with them. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) has always been sufficient for me to play my videos and I haven't installed a coded pack now for years ...

You can install the [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/siw-download.html) freeware version to figure out the video card that's in your machine and from there download the correct driver via the manufacturer's home page, e.g. [NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/content/global/global.php) and [AIT RADEON](http://www.amd.com/us/products/pages/graphics.aspx)